# string conversion to array by commaseparated using php

Tags: php, mysql, curl, pdo

I am fetching values from online using curl from given url working fine, but here the problem is, giving combined string like - first url had one value returning and next url returning with 5 values so total six values displaying as like this, `"testdata1testdata2testdata3testdata4testdata5testdata6testdata7"` i need to insert these data to mysql it is storing like string how to separate by comma.

```
function data($urls,$v)
{
    foreach ($urls as $url => $key) 
    {
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $key);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);  
        $str = curl_exec($curl);  
        curl_close($curl);
        $html= str_get_html($str);
        foreach($html->find('.name') as $element)
        {
$grab = $element->innertext;

            $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE table SET word='$grab' where url='$v[$url]'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the data actually look like? You'll need common ground to be able to split it because right now it's going to be perceived as one ugly-ass string.

Comment: may be you can try this at remote url send respons in json then decode json here

Comment: i am looking to Url1 = array([1]=>data),Url2= array([1]=>data1,[2]=>data2,[3]=>data3)

Comment: are there always numbers ath the end of second variable?

Comment: Can you update the remote code ?

Comment: no numbers it is example only.

Comment: You can use 'explode(..)' to split a string on commas. Your title is however lying, since your data does not contain commas...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You wrote in comments, that there are no numbers in the variables past. In that case it is impossible to guess where the delimeters should be **unless you know** i.e.

- the size of each parameter (maybe it is constant?)
- have got array of ALL possible variables?
- know something more about the variables structure?

**If You don't, the answer is: You can't, sorry**. As ***Shah Rukh*** suggested in comments, try to use i.e. json to pass the parameters to another page / subpage / script.

---

If every variable is ended with a number, you can try this solution:

(I assumed that every variable passed is ended up with a number, so You must be really careful and be sure that this is the exact format, that the data will always be sent in).

```
function every($matches) {
    return $matches[1].',';
}

$input = 'testdata1testdata2testdata3testdata4testdata5testdata6testdata7';
$input = preg_replace_callback( "|(\d+)|", "every", $input);
$input = explode(',', rtrim($input, ","));
print_r($input);
```

Will print out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => testdata1
    [1] => testdata2
    [2] => testdata3
    [3] => testdata4
    [4] => testdata5
    [5] => testdata6
    [6] => testdata7
)
```

I hope it helps, however **I think that you should change some logic of your application**, and **send the data between pages in a more user friendly format** as json for example. Best regards!

PS. If You want to get rid of "test", you can do for example:

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) $input[$key] = substr($value, 4);
```

*But remember to be careful when modifying arrays at the same time you are iterating them through.*

Comment: NO problem, glad to help! If this answer is good enough, please accept it, if not, just comment here and I will do my best to help again.